# Передача колонки из DataGridView в ComboBox

Tags: c#, winforms

Такой вопрос. Есть 2 разные таблицы DataGridView, условно DG1 и DG2, находящиеся на разных формах и есть форма с полями и комбобоксом для добавления данных в DG2. Как из DG1 считать определенную колонку и передать в комбобокс? Таблицы все обычные.

Comment: WinForms или WPF? Что означает DG: DataGrid или DataGridView? Дайте больше информации.

Comment: означает DataGridView

Comment: WinForms и DataGridView